# deviceready event not fireing in phonegap build app based on 1.6.1

Tags: ios, events, cordova

BACKGROUND:

I am running a phonegap app that I am building using phonegap build (1.6.1).

android build seems to work just fine,
however on iOS (Iphone 3GS 16M iOS: 5.0.1 (9A405) ) I never get the `deviceready` event.

I am trying to figure out what am I missing here.

QUESTIONS:
1. Does it matter if the binding of the `deviceready` event comes before or after including `phonegap.js` ?
2. Could it be that the event is happening "too early" and my handler is not yet bound to it ?
3. Is there a polling based way to figure out that the device is ready?
4. Where should handling of deviceready be done relating to JQuery's `$(document').ready` ?

MY CODE:
my current code tries to synchronize 3 things:
1. JQuery's `.ready` event
2. PhoneGap's `deviceready` event
3. (careful) polling results on window.navigator.device.platform

in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.myapp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.myapp={
            deviceReady:false,
            JQueryReady:false,
            started:false,
            logbuf:[]
        }

        function log(m){
            window.myapp.logbuf.push(m);
            console.debug(window.myapp.logbuf.join('||'));
            var  el=document.getElementById('container');
            if (el!=null) {
                el.innerHTML+=', ' + window.myapp.logbuf.join('||') ;
                window.myapp.logbuf=[];
            }
        }

        //Wait for device
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.myapp.deviceReady=true;
            log('phonegap deviceready event fired');
            startIfAllReady();
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function pollDevice(){
            if (window && window.navigator && window.navigator.device && window.navigator.device.platform ) {
                log('polling found device');
                window.myapp.deviceReady=true;
                startIfAllReady();  
            }
            else {
                log('polling');
                window.setTimeout(arguments.callee,500);
            }
        }

        pollDevice();

        //Wait for jquery
        $(document).ready(
            function(){
                window.myapp.JQueryReady=true;
                log('jquery document.ready event fired');
                startIfAllReady();
            }
        );              


        function startIfAllReady(){
            log('startIfAllReady window.myapp.JQueryReady=' + window.myapp.JQueryReady + ' window.myapp.deviceReady=' + window.myapp.deviceReady + ' window.myapp.started=' + window.myapp.started );
            if (window.myapp.deviceReady && window.myapp.JQueryReady && window.myapp.started==false) {
                log('starting');
                started=true;
                renderClient();
            }
            else {
                log('cant start');                  
            }
        }

        function renderClient(){
            log('renderClient called - RETURNING !');
            return;
            window.setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0, 1)},100);
            log('create myappClient');
            $('#myappClientContainer').empty().myappClient(
                {width:$(window).width(),
                 height:$(window).height()
                }
            );
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/client.css" />
    <style>
        html , body { margin:0px; background-color:gray;}
    </style>

    <title>myapp</title>
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:100%">

<script>
    log('body script executing');
</script>
<div style="width:100%" id="myappClientContainer">DEFAULT HTML</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE RESULTS:
in a regulat browser (chrome) I get:

```
DEFAULT HTML  
polling||body script executing||jquery document.ready event fired  
startIfAllReady window.myapp.JQueryReady=true window.myapp.deviceReady=false window.myapp.started=false   
cant start   
polling   
polling   
polling   
... (and polling....)
```

on Iphone:

```
DEFAULT HTML  
polling||body script executing||jquery document.ready event fired  
startIfAllReady window.myapp.JQueryReady=true window.myapp.deviceReady=false window.myapp.started=false   
cant start
```

As you can see - no "phonegap deviceready event fired" anywhere, nor does the polling seem to work :(

notice that on the iphone, only single "polling" log entry at the start...
can't iPhone handle onTimeout ?
why dont I get the deviceready event ?!

Another thing I noticed:
When (phonegap)building with debug set, 
I can see the device/app in the PhoneGapBuild weinre debug window for some short time and then it just disappears.

Thanks

UPDATE:
my polling loop above is wrong,
It should look for window.navigator.platform

anyway I dropped it all together.
something Is just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like i neglected to update this Q.
anyway the probelm was that 'console.debug' does not exist within winere and so my code was failing.

Eyal

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, my problem was solved by adding
    ..script src="phonegap.js...
to my html file

source:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/javascript_events_not_working_with_android_phonegap_build_xcode

I was under the impression that the build process added that ipmort and I'm especially confused because everything was fine when I was bypassing the deviceready event. Hope this helps.

Comment: The build adds the JS itself but not the script line that loads it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to attach the phoneGap deviceReady event on body load, like this:

```
<script>
function onBodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    }
</script>

<body onload="onBodyLoad()"> .. html ... </body>
```

Comment: yep, well, it does nt work for my code. currently being debugged by the good people from phonegap/nitobi/adobe.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles across this answer, it is patently not true.